# Initialize a service on app startup without initializer

Tags: ember.js, service

I have a service in Ember 2.18 named testing. e.g.

export default Service.extend({ //some code })

I need to be able to initialize this testing service in the app from within the service if possible. Essentially want to inject the service across the app globally from within the service without using an initializer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Services are all instantiated on app boot.

But you cannot inject them everywhere by default without an initializer. I actually recommend against this, as it can lead to hard-to-trace behavior.

So, to use the service within another service without an initializer, you must do:

```
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend({
  testing: service(),
})
```

#### Update: using a service from a helper

(from here: https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-router-helpers/blob/master/addon/helpers/is-active.js)

```
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import Helper from '@ember/component/helper';
import handleQueryParams from '../utils/handle-query-params';

export default Helper.extend({
  router: service(),

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.addObserver('router.currentURL', this, 'recompute');
  },

  compute(_params) {
    let params = handleQueryParams(_params);
    return this.get('router').isActive(...params);
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm actually looking to use the service in a helper. But first things first I need to have the service initialized by itself and not from another service.

Comment: added an example of how to use a service from a helper.
what do you mean "have the service initialized by itself"? 
all services are instantiated on app boot

Comment: The end result was initializing an instance through app.js, thanks for your input

Comment: what do you mean through app.js?, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: const testService = instance.lookup('service:testing');
testService.initialize();

Comment: Oh, you just have a method called initialize? You can still call that from a helper from an injected service. No need to lookup from the di container